# How to cache an authentication token using Cordova and Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: cordova, azure, authentication, caching, azure-mobile-services

How do I cache a user's google authentication token using the client-flow method?

The below code successfully authenticates the user but it does it everytime the user closes and reopens the app.

```
loginAzure = function (loginSuccess, handleError) {
    AzureDbSvc.client.login('google')
    .then(function () {
        // Obtain information about the authenticated use
        var url = AzureDbSvc.client.applicationUrl + '/.auth/me';
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', 
           AzureDbSvc.client.currentUser.mobileServiceAuthenticationToken);
        fetch(url, { headers: headers })
            .then(function (data) {
                var user_json = data.json();
                console.log('user_json:' + user_json);
                return user_json;
            }).then(function (tuser) {
                authUser.email = tuser[0].user_id;
                for (i = 0; i < tuser[0].user_claims.length; i++) {
                    switch (tuser[0].user_claims[i].typ) {
                        case "name":
                            authUser.userName = tuser[0].user_claims[i].val;
                            break;
                        case "picture":
                            authUser.picture = tuser[0].user_claims[i].val;
                            break;
                        case "locale":
                            authUser.locale = tuser[0].user_claims[i].val;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                loginSuccess(authUser);
            }
        );
    }, handleError);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version:

1. Store the JSON representation of the client.currentUser in localStorage
2. When the app starts, restore the client.currentUser to a temp variable.  Test the mobileServiceAuthenticationToken value to see if it has expired.  If it has, discard and skip step 3.
3. Assign the temp variable to client.currentUser
4. If you don't have a valid token in client.currentUser, call client.login('google'), then store in localStorage (for step 1 to read)

You can do the same with the output of /.auth/me - only read it if you don't already have it.  You should only have to read /.auth/me when the token changes.

Comment: How do I check the mobileServiceAuthenticationToken value to see if it has expired? I searched but did not find a simple solution.